# Task freeze the GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface, async-await, task

I have this situation: from a task the function "Automation()" is called which should run in background, but the GUI is freezing. GUI is freezing also when I use a Task.Delay. I want the task to continue running only after the "Automation()" function has done it's work, but the GUI should not freeze while Automation() function is running. How can I accomplish this? I do not understand why the GUI freezes. Thank you.

```
string pair = "A";
private async Task Start()
    {
        DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1000);
        while (true)
        {
            if (pair =="A")
            {
                if (TaskA == null) { A_cancelTokenSource.Dispose(); A_cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); TaskA = TaskPairA(A_cancelTokenSource.Token); }
                else { if (TaskA.IsCompleted == true) { TaskA.Dispose(); TaskA = null; A_cancelTokenSource.Dispose(); A_cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); TaskA = TaskPairA(A_cancelTokenSource.Token); } }
            }
            if (pair =="B")
            {
                if (TaskB == null) { B_cancelTokenSource.Dispose(); B_cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); TaskB = TaskPairB(B_cancelTokenSource.Token); }
                else { if (TaskB.IsCompleted == true) { TaskB.Dispose(); TaskB = null; B_cancelTokenSource.Dispose(); B_cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); TaskB = TaskPairB(B_cancelTokenSource.Token); } }
            }
            await Task.Delay(500);
            if (DateTime.Now >= dueTime) { GetAccountData(); dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1000); }
        }
    }


    public async Task TaskPairA(CancellationToken ctA)
    {
        while (true)
        {
        // other code.....

        while (automationFlag == true) { Task.Delay(300); } // This  alone freeze the user interface
        Automation(); // This  alone freeze the user interface

       
        // other code.....   Continue here only after "Automation()" is done
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you know that the `Automation()` runs on a background thread? I am not seeing any `Task.Run` or `new Thread` in your code.

Comment: Is using a Task not automatically free the GUI?

Comment: Nope, calling an `async` method can still block the UI thread, if the method does not return an incomplete `Task` immediately. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592957/async-task-is-freezing-the-ui) question, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671919/gui-freezes-when-using-async-await). `Task.Run` is the solution, but you must be careful to avoid any interaction with UI elements from inside the `Task.Run` delegate.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working like this: await Task.Run(async () => { await Automation(); });

Comment: Nice! FYI according to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the asynchronous `Automation` method should be named `AutomationAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to add `await` keywords there.

```
while (automationFlag == true) { await Task.Delay(300); } 
await Automation(); // I think it is also async Task
```

Comment: The GUI is freezing even if I add await in front of Automation(); It does not freeze only if I use  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Automation("A"); }); But then it will not be awaiten...

Answer (score -1):

```
while(true) // it makes your GUI freeze
```

You should use another thread and `Dispatcher` not to making UI lock

Not to make CPU hit 100%, you should use `Task.Delay()` inside of `while` loop as well.

```
Task.Run(async() =>
{
    while(true) 
    { 
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        // it only works in WPF
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // Do something on the UI thread.
        });
    }
}
```

If there was more information about `Automation();`, I'd give you better answer.